# How to create a curved shape that encircles circles?

Tags: math, graphics, 2d

Is there a known way / algorithm that can give me a 2d curve or set of curves that encircles certain shapes, for example circles, like this:
[image: Curve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no analytic way to do this, but if you can discretize your shapes you could use the [convex hull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) to get a curve that encompasses your original shapes. Like the algorithm name suggests, the resulting shape will be convex and won't bend inward toward the spaces between the circles as in your picture. The algorithm is O(n log n) in 2 and 3 dimensions.